# Why print(print()) not work like print(type(2)) in Lua?

Tags: printing, types, lua

I have been messing with Lua for a couple of days and I have figured out some things that made me think twice. **I have not yet read the reference manual Lua 5.3 because it seems to complicated** , I will soon check on it.

**Ok in lua 5.3  , we know print() returns back  *nil* and prints a space.**

```
>print(print(print()))

                        --this prints three spaces 
                        --but print() returns nil so print(nil) should
                        --print nil. But instead it is printing 3 spaces


>print(type(2))  
number                  --this prints a number since type(2) returns a 
                        --number , but this doesn't work with print(print()) 
                        --why?
```

Comment: print returns nothinng. So `print(print()) ` is equal to `print() print()`

Answer (score 6):

Returning nothing from a function is not the same as returning `nil`. The results may be confusing as most of the time returning nothing is interpreted similar to returning `nil`, but in the case of `print`, it doesn't print `nil`, because nothing is returned.

You can see the difference with the following examples:

```
print(select('#', (function() return end)())) -- prints 0
print(select('#', (function() return nil end)())) -- prints 1
```

In the first case the number of returned values is 0, but in the second case this number is 1, so when printed, it will show `nil` as you expect.

> we know print() returns back nil and prints a space.

This is incorrect on both counts: `print()` doesn't return `nil`; it returns nothing. It also doesn't print a space, but it adds a newline after all its values are printed, so you probably see three lines printed in your first example.